# How to make objects fall and stick to a certain target?

Tags: game-physics, aframe

I'm trying to have objects (entities) falling from the sky and sticking to a certain target (point/object). I've been looking into the aframe-extras, more specifically into the [physics system](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-physics-system) because I was thinking that if I could specify the gravity point into an object, the other entities falling from the sky would stick around it. But still not quite sure how I could do this.

Any new ideas for this problem are very welcome :)

Comment: Have you tried constraints within the physics system?

Comment: @ngokevin I'm not sure what you mean by constraints? Could you give an example?

Comment: https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-physics-system#constraint

Comment: right. Thanks. I've looked into it before but couldn't think of a way the constraint properties could be used for this specific problem. Gonna dig little further.

Comment: https://twitter.com/donrmccurdy/status/894335912779235332